# Why do most audio src tags use ogg and mp3

Tags: html, audio, mp3, wav, ogg

I have noticed that most tutorials regarding HTML5 audio tags always use mp3 and ogg formats, Why do most developers use mp3 and ogg format in their html5 audio source tags? Why can't it be mp3 and wav?  Is it a rule of the thumb to use mp3 and ogg on audio source tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wave is generally uncompressed audio data, which is not practical for web applications.

Comment: care to explain why it is not practical for web applications?

Comment: .Wav files are uncompressed == large == slow download == annoyance

Comment: but wav files deliver better sound quality, are wav files to be considered if audio quality is important?

Comment: Better is subjective term. Ogg and mp3s are **good enough**. Most of the people browsing web don't have proffesional-grade audio equipment do hear a difference between SACD and CD, and even between FLAC and mp3. And oh, wave can have **any** bitrate, so for example 32kbps wave is entirely possible, though the quality will be **a lot** worse than (for example) low-profile AAC.

Comment: Read and listen to this, mp3 file 25% of wav >> http://www.noiseaddicts.com/2010/04/sound-test-difference-between-wav-vs-mp3/

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz  That being said, I forgot that majority of internet users are not audiophiles. I guess I'll go with mp3 and ogg. thanks, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

mp3 and especially ogg are easy to stream and can contain video/audio/text

as mentioned above .wav is totally uncompressed-audio only